# Check if $(this) is set

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a function, say:

```
function some_name( that ) {
// do something here
}
```

This function gets called in 2 places.  Place 1 is at document.ready and place 2 is when a button is clicked.

So:

```
// document.ready
function some_name();

...

// button click
function some_name( $(this) );
```

Now going back to the function itself, how do I check if `that` has been set?

Comment: `typeof that !== 'undefined'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is using [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof):

```
function some_name(that) {
    if (typeof that != "undefined") {
        // do smth with that
    } else {
        // do smth without that
    }
}
```

Another option is using [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments):

```
function some_name(that) {
    if (arguments.length) {
        // do smth with that
    } else {
        // do smth without that
    }
}
```

---

If you also need to check if element `$(this)` exists on a page, you can use [`length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/):

```
if (that.length) {
    // element exists
} else {
    // element does not exist
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function some_name(that) {
    if (that != undefined) {
        alert('that is good!');
    }
}
```